# Installing Nvidia drivers prevents boot

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I recently built a computer with a RTX3070. I was recently able to install Ubuntu 22.04 and login.

Currently I'm using the Nouveau drivers, but I want to install the Nvidia drivers. However, ANY Nvidia driver I install makes it so that I can no longer boot into Ubuntu when I restart. I've tried 470, 515, 525, and more.

When I install the driver and reboot, I get a black terminal with the message:

`Nvidiafb: cannot requests PCI regions`.

System info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Motherboard: Gigabyte Z690I Aorus Ultra DDR4
Graphics Card: RTX3070 Founders Editions
BIOS is on latest version.
```

Any ideas what's happening here? What info can I provide to make debugging easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have driver issues in Ubuntu 22.04 with a fairly new high-end graphics card from 2021. Such issues are often solved by updating your Ubuntu release to the latest version. This is one of the things that non-LTS Ubuntu releases are for. Maybe upgrading to Ubuntu 22.10 kinetic would do some good, if not 22.10 kinetic then Ubuntu 23.04 lunar will be released in April of this year.

Comment: That actually worked! Such a simple solution, thank you so much. I had tried dozens of different things for hours before this.